# Page not found error when creating a simple module

Tags: page-controller

I have my first module in drupal 8 with three files in modules section of my drupal:

**hello_world.routing.yml:**

```
hello_world:
    path: '/hello/world'
    defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::hello'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

**hello_world.info.yml:** ( in modules/hello_world/src/Controller directory)

```
name: Hello World!
type: module
description: Say Hello World
package: Custom
core: 8.x
```

**HelloWorldController.php**:

```
namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;


class HelloWorldController {

    public function hello() {

        return array(
                '#title' => 'Hello World!!!',
                '#markup' => 'Here is some content.',
            );
    }
}

?>
```

however, when I press clear all caches button and run code again. I just have *Page not found* problem.
[image]

Comment: An obvious question but have you definitely enabled the module? In your message you also say you have your hello_world.info.yml 
 in "modules/hello_world/src/Controller" it should be in the root of your hellow_world module folder. Or was that just a mistake and you meant your controller is in there

Comment: The YML pasted above, the indentation looks a little off and there are other oddities like the closing PHP tag, etc. Is the URL in the browser correct? The route has it defined at just `/hello/world` but the browser URL is `/drupaltest/hello/world` - or do you have Drupal installed in a subdirectory?

Comment: Thank you for response. I do not know where should I put my modules folder. I thought that it should be in modules sub folder after root folder.

Comment: I just put HelloWorldController.php in modules/hello_world/src/Controller. my yml files are in hello_world folder

Comment: HelloWorldController.php is in : C:\xampp\htdocs\drupaltest\modules\hello_world\src\Controller  ,               yml files are in hello_world folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello_world.info.yml sould be in modules/hello_world/

then check if the hello_world is enabled and rebuild cache

Comment: Yes. I did do it.  I have C:\xampp\htdocs\drupaltest\modules\hello_world and inside of hello_world folder I have  three mentioned above files. where is root? should I change  my direction? I just download drupal 8, change its name to drupaltest and put it on my htdocs of xmapp

Comment: thank you. it is work now. I rebuilt  the module again and reinstall module again